# How to convert a sequence of Tuples into JSON array in spray

Tags: arrays, json, scala, spray-json

I have an array of student IDs which is dynamic in scala.

```
val studentIds = Seq(1,2,3,4....)
```

I should convert them into a JSON array in Spray JSON.

like

```
[
 {"student_id" : 1 },
 {"student_id" : 2 },
 {"student_id" : 3 },
]
```

How to do it without a case class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Maps. Each map will be translated directly to an json object.

```scala
import spray.json._
import DefaultJsonProtocol._

val studentIds = Seq(1,2,3,4).map(s => Map("student_id" -> s))

println(studentIds.toJson)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code snippet-

```js
import spray.json.{JsNumber, JsObject}
val studentIds = Seq(1,2,3,4).map{x => JsObject("student_id" -> JsNumber(x))}
  
println(studentIds)
```